# Laravel - Inserting Two Select Values to Database

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to insert the destination input value to database but it is giving me an error see here. what is the problem?

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'destination' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `aircraft_flights` (`flight_number`, `iata_flight_number`, `flight_date`, `departure_time`, `arrival_time`, `from_location`, `destination`, `aircraft_id`) values (FK2457, SQ1, 2018-03-02T04:03, 2018-04-04T04:25, 2018-05-06T16:02, Philippines, , 4))

here is my Form Input of Destination

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
    {{Form::label('from_location', 'From')}} 
    {{Form::select('from_location', trans('countries'),null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select where you From'])}}<br>
</div>
<br>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
    {{Form::label('destination', 'Destination Country')}} 
    {{Form::select('destination', trans('countries'),null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select where is your Destination'])}}<br>
</div>
<br>
```

my ***Migration***

```
 $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('flight_number');
        $table->string('iata_flight_number');
        $table->dateTime('flight_date');
        $table->dateTime('departure_time');
        $table->dateTime('arrival_time');
        $table->string('from_location');
        $table->string('destination');
        $table->integer('aircraft_id');
```

my ***Controller***

```
 $aircraftFlight = new AircraftFlights;
    $aircraftFlight->flight_number = $request->input('flight_number');
    $aircraftFlight->iata_flight_number = $request->input('iata_flight_number');
    $aircraftFlight->flight_date     = $request->input('flight_date');
    $aircraftFlight->departure_time = $request->input('departure_time');
    $aircraftFlight->arrival_time = $request->input('arrival_time');
    $aircraftFlight->from_location = $request->input('from_location');
    $aircraftFlight->destination     = $request->input('destination ');
    $aircraftFlight->aircraft_id = $request->input('aircraft_id');

    $aircraftFlight->save();

    return redirect('/admin/aircraftflights')->with('success', 'Flight Created');
```

my ***Model***

```
protected $table = 'aircraft_flights';
// Primary Key
public $primaryKey = 'id';
// Timestamps
public $timestamps = false;
```

Comment: i guess you have make ```destination``` column ```NULL``` in database. Because ```destination``` column in not allowing  ```NULL```  value

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... it cant be null because i've insert a value on destination

Comment: check what are you getting in ```dd($request->all())``` in controller before ```$aircraftFlight = new AircraftFlights;``` line.

Comment: Nevermind solved it cause the store function destination has space

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `destination` input from what I read. `from_location` is `Philippines` in your example and `destination` is NULL then aircraft_id is `4`.

When you add this to your `Model` it should fix the problem (NULL can be passed then)

```
protected static $strictMode = false;
```

Comment: then something is wrong with your input (if you input data and it gives null anyways)

Comment: Please try to not select destination and check if strictMode false is working

Answer (score 0):

You need to change default value for the form from NULL to empty string

```
{{Form::select('destination', trans('countries'),'',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select where is your Destination'])}}<br>
```

**Or**

you need to change `$table->string('destination')->nullable();` (allow null values) and run Migration again.

The same issue will be for `$aircraftFlight->from_location` and where you send null values

Comment: But i dont want it to be null im also selecting values for each of them i dont want the value to be null

Comment: still gving me error. it cant be null because i insert a value on destination

Answer (score 0):

hi in your database make destination nullable

```
 $table->string('destination')->nullable();
```

and  `$aircraftFlight->destination     = $request->input('destination');`
delete espace